# Converting 1 channel PCM to wav file in Golang from streaming serial device

Tags: go, audio, pcm

I'm using the go-audio package to convert a stream of PCM bytes to a wav file. The file is created and I can generate spikes when listening to the audio which sounds like a 52k modem but not very useful.

```
func readAudio() {

    flag.Parse()

    // Output file.
    out, err := os.Create("output.wav")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer out.Close()

    // 8 kHz, 16 bit, 1 channel, WAV.
    e := wav.NewEncoder(out, 8000, 16, 1, 1)

    // Program Info
    log.Printf("Starting with port %s at baud rate %d", com, baud)

    // Setup Serial Port
    //c := &serial.Config{Name: "COM45", Baud: 115200, ReadTimeout: time.Second * 5}
    c := &serial.Config{Name: com, Baud: 115200}
    s, err := serial.OpenPort(c)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    for {

        log.Print("Reading Bytes in...")

        buf := make([]byte, 320)

        _, err := s.Read(buf)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }

        // Print Bytes Read
        log.Println(buf)

        audioBuf, err := newAudioIntBuf(buf)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }

        // Write buffer to output file. This writes a RIFF header and the PCM chunks from the audio.IntBuffer.
        if err := e.Write(audioBuf); err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        if err := e.Close(); err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
    }

}

func newAudioIntBuf(byteBuf []byte) (*audio.IntBuffer, error) {
    buf := audio.IntBuffer{
        Format: &audio.Format{
            NumChannels: 1,
            SampleRate:  8000,
        },
    }

    for _, s := range byteBuf {
        buf.Data = append(buf.Data, int(s))
    }
    //err := binary.Read(r, binary.LittleEndian, &sample)
    return &buf, nil
}
```

I believe I have all the correct bitrates, and the searial sends out blocks of data at 320 bytes per block. I'm not sure if that matters.

Comment: I suspect your problem lies in => for _, s := range byteBuf {
        buf.Data = append(buf.Data, int(s))
    }

Comment: Are you sure the device is outputting 16bit/8khz PCM?

Comment: yes, I was able to test the raw pcm by importing it to Audacity. 16 bit Mono at 8000Hz